# optimization of iteration of 2loops using java8-11

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a list containing keys and a map. Now i need to do some operation when list value matches with key of map.
For that I have written below code

```
list.stream().foreach(listelement ->{
mapelements.forEach((k,v) -> {
if (listelement.trim().equalscaseignorecase(k))
//Do someting
});
});
```

can anyone plz suggest me how to optimize this code using java 8-11. Like using stream(), filter() etc features of java8

Comment: Why do you think it >needs< optimizing?  Which step is the performance hot spot?

Comment: Can we use filter and a single iteration anyhow? Thats what i mean by optimizing the code

Answer (score 1):

There is no good way to optimize this with the data structure you have designed.

The problem is that the keys in the map are case sensitive, and you cannot do an efficient case insensitive lookup on a (standard) `Map` class where the `get` method does case sensitive lookup.  You have to iterate the map entries for each list entry ... like you are currently doing.  Using filters or other stream features won't solve that.

To fix this, you need to change the data structure so that you can do `O(1)` or `O(logN)` case insensitive lookup.

Option #1:  Use a `HashMap` and make the keys in the map case insensitive; e.g. convert them to lowercase before you create the map entries.

Option #2:  Use a `TreeMap` with a case insensitive `Comparator`.  (That has other consequences.  Read the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html).)

Comment: I have already implemented using hashmap.. but problem is that I am very new to java8 coding..I need to use fliter and any other java8 feature and modify my existing code

Comment: Well ... like I said ... filters and other Java 8 features won't solve the problem.  No matter how needful you are.  You don't use a screwdriver to hammer in nails.